# A library for converting general cryptocurrency's private key to address

Tags: javascript, addresses, private-key

Is there a library on npm to convert a given private key and cryptocurrency's name to an address? E.g. Tron and Ethereum give different addresses when using the same private key:

```typescript
let addrEthereum = '0x0835f0b852064b10a6b92aac13f323f07d524ee4'
let addrTron = 'TAid2S2NiavsWVAvkqXAmQs14tbsM47qkG'
```

and the separate address derivations are

```typescript
function deriveTron(privk: string) {
  return TronWeb.address.fromPrivateKey(privk);
}

function deriveEth(privk: string) {
  let bprivk = Buffer.from(privk, 'hex')
  let bpubk = EthereumAddress.fromPrivateKey(bprivk)
  return bpubk.toString()
}
```